# Raise event after inherited class method completed

Tags: c#, events, inheritance

I'm new to using inherited classes, so I may be missing something completly obvious.  I have two classes, A and B, that both inherit some other class Z.  Class Z has a number of methods etc.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to create an event (or just some method) in class A and B that is triggered *after* some method in class Z finishes...

Is there a way to do that?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using abstract methods:**

*Subclasses override abstract method from base class.*

```
abstract class Z {
    abstract doSomethingElse();

    doSomething(){
        //main logic

        doSomethingElse();
    }
}

class A : Z {
    doSomethingElse(){
        //subclass logic
    }
}

class B : Z {
    doSomethingElse(){
        //subclass logic
    }
}
```

**Calling base by convention:**

*Override virtual methods from base class & invoke base method at the beginning*

```
class Z {
    doSomething(){
        //main logic
    }
}

class A : Z {
    doSomething(){
        base.doSomething()

        //subclass logic
    }
}

class B : Z {
    doSomething(){
        base.doSomething()

        //subclass logic
    }
}
```

**Delegate injection:**

*Require a delegate in the superclass constructor. Invoke the delegate.*

```
class Z {
    delegate somethingDone

    Z(_somethingDone){
        somethingDone = _somethingDone
    }

    doSomething(){
        //main logic

        somethingDone()
    }
}

class A : Z {
    A() : base(onSomethingDone){

    }

    onSomethingDone(){
        //subclass logic
    }
}

class B : Z {
    B() : base(onSomethingDone){

    }

    onSomethingDone(){
        //subclass logic
    }
}
```

**Event Subscription:**

*Fire an event when the action happens. Other classes subscribe to the event*

```
class Z {
    doSomething(){
        //main logic

        fireEvent("SomethingDone")
    }
}

class A {
    A(){
        subscribeToEvent("SomethingDone", onSomethingDone)
    }

    onSomethingDone(){
        //subclass logic
    }
}

class B {
    B(){
        subscribeToEvent("SomethingDone", onSomethingDone)
    }

    onSomethingDone(){
        //subclass logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a protected virtual method on class Z and implement it in class A and B:

```
class Z
{
protected virtual AfterMethodCalled(){}

public void Method()
{
//do its job
AfterMethodCalled();
}
}

classA:Z
{
protected override AfterMethodCalled()
{
//do its job 
}
}
```

**Edit**
If you want to raise and event after something has happened in your code and at the same time let the derived classes to changed the event behavior you can do something like this :

```
class Z
    {
    public event EventHandler AfterMethodCalled;//defines a delegate to be used as an event. 

    protected virtual OnAfterMethodCalled
    {
    if(AfterMethodCalled!=null) //if there's at least one subscriber to this event
    AfterMethodCalled(this,EventArgs.Empty); //raise the event
    }

    public void Method()
    {
    //do the job
    OnAfterMethodCalled();
    }

then each sub class can either subscribe to this event and even change the base behavior by overriding this virtual method:

class A:
{

protected override OnAfterMethodCalled()
{
//do the job;
base.OnAfterMethodCalled(); // you can omit this line if you want to prevent raising the event
}
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me what you want is an event, take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx for more info on events, but a simple event implementation like this should do the trick

**Base Class Z**

```
public event Action MyEvent;

public void MyMethod()
{
    // a lot of work...

    SomethingHappened();
}

protected virtual void SomethingHappened()
{
    Action currentEvent = MyEvent;

    if (currentEvent != null)
    {
        currentEvent();
    }
}
```

**Inheriting Class (A or B)**

```
public A()
{
    MyEvent += DoAdditionalWork;
}

public void DoAdditionalWork()
{

}
```

The trick is to publish an event, and raise it when your method is done, then any consumer can subscribe to it, and do its job when your method finishes executing.